# Truffle Build doesn't work

Tags: truffle

```
module.exports = {
build: {
//"index.html":"index.html",
//"app.js": [
//"javascripts/app.js"
//],
//"app.css": [ 
//"stylesheets/app.css"
//],
//"images/": "images/"
},
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

This is my truffle.js config file(the reason I have commented all those lines is that I have not created them yet.)
when I run the truffle build command, I get the following error

```
Build configuration can no longer be specified as an object. Please see our documentation for an updated list of supported build configurations.
```

I went through http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/getting_started/build/ but there it's the same. Version Details-
Truffle v3.4.7 (core: 3.4.7)
Solidity v0.4.13 (solc-js)

The build proceeds with the new config file according to the Truffle version 3 docs.

```
var DefaultBuilder = require("truffle-default-builder");
module.exports = {
build: new DefaultBuilder({
"index.html":"index.html",
"app.js":[
"javascripts/app.js"]
}),
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

But now I am getting a new error

```
Compiling ./contracts/ConvertLib.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/MetaCoin.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts
Error: Couldn't find file at .//app/index.html. 
    at DefaultBuilder.expect (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/truffle-default-builder/index.js:281:17)
    at /home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/truffle-default-builder/index.js:179:15
    at /home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:375:13
    at iterate (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at Object.async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:281:9)
    at Object.async.inject.async.foldl.async.reduce (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:374:15)
    at DefaultBuilder.process_files (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/truffle-default-builder/index.js:173:9)
    at DefaultBuilder.process_target (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/truffle-default-builder/index.js:224:8)
    at /home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/truffle-default-builder/index.js:263:10
    at /home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:181:20
    at iterate (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at Object.async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:281:9)
    at Object.async.forEachSeries.async.eachSeries (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:214:22)
    at DefaultBuilder.process_all_targets (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/truffle-default-builder/index.js:262:9)
    at DefaultBuilder.build (/home/ankit-x3/TRUFFLE/node_modules/truffle-default-builder/index.js:132:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:103776:17.
```

Problem solved. I missed the app directory needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the old documentation (for truffle *v2.x*). The new documentation for Truffle *v.3.x* is [here](http://truffleframework.com/docs/)

The migration process between the versions is explained [here](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/upgrading-from-truffle-2-to-3):

> Build Pipeline: No more builder, by default In Truffle 1.0 and 2.0,
>   things were heavily geared toward building web applications, and so
>   Truffle shipped with a default build pipeline that could get your dapp
>   up and running quickly. This build pipeline was magical: It did
>   everything for you, and you didn't have to lift a finger. This was
>   good for some use cases, but it became evidently clear that in any
>   other use case the pipeline was very brittle.
>
> Over the last year, Ethereum-enabled applications have only been
>   growing. What started out as solely a platform for web application,
>   now dapps can be written in native languages and run as standalone
>   applications on mobile and the desktop. Truffle has always intended to
>   support these use cases, and so that's why we removed the default
>   build pipeline from Truffle. You can still write your own custom build
>   pipeline if you'd like to tightly integrate it with Truffle, but by
>   default Truffle will focus on continuing to be the best tool for smart
>   contracts around. We'll let the better build pipelines – like webpack,
>   browserify, Grunt, Metalsmith – do the job of, well, building.
>
> Now, just because the build pipeline has been removed by default
>   doesn't mean you don't have options. At Truffle, we care about your
>   developer experience and so would never leave you hanging. In general
>   there are two options for you to choose from, but for the latter
>   option what you'll do is heavily dependent on which build tool (i.e.,
>   webpack) you choose to use. Let's go over the options below.

All of that means that the Truffle config file can't contain a build setup anymore. Just remove the `build` part:

*truffle.js*

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: this doesn't work too.

Comment: Same exception?

Comment: I don't remember it now. But this got resolved with the following truffle.js file -
var DefaultBuilder = require("truffle-default-builder");
module.exports = {
build: new DefaultBuilder({
"index.html":"index.html",
"app.js":[
"javascripts/app.js"]
}),
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};

Comment: now i am facing a new problem.

Comment: Glad to see it worked. This is strange anyway. It could be interesting to write an issue for further analysis on [the Truffle GitHub](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues). For the new problem, please create a new question

Comment: the new problem is related to the truffle build process only. Hence I have edited this question only.

Answer (score 0):

Rename file truffle.js to truffle-config.js , and run your command again

Comment: got the same error.